# Определение размера fstream открытого с флагом ios::binary

Tags: c++

Есть .txt файл, необходимо считать его размеры, после этого побайтно переписать данные. Соответственно необходимо знать первоначальный размер файла. Пробовал через [метод отсюда через tellg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file) - получал -1, далее попробовал метод [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file) используя `gcount` - получал 0. Первый метод работает если добавить флаг `app` при открытии. Есть ещё какие-нибудь способы кроме как проход по файлу циклом?

Добавил проверку, при наличии флага `binary` ошибка:

```
void itsg06(std::string path)
{
    std::fstream file(path, std::ios::binary);
    if( !file.good() )
        std::cout << "\nErr\n";
    else
    { 
        for( std::string line; std::getline( file, line ); )
        {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Получение -1 обычно говорит о том, что файл открыть не удалось или произошла еще какая-то другая ошибка.

Comment: @VTT добавил скриншот - файл открывается нормально. При записи в файл, используя этот же поток, содержимое файла меняется

Comment: Во-первых не стоит вставлять текст (и консольный вывод) картинкой. Во-вторых открылся файл или нет в видимом куске кода не проверяется, также непонятно, к чему относится текст в консоли. Следует привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VTT благодарю за совет. Если установить binary, то поднимается faibit

Comment: Второй аргумент в конструкторе - это набор флагов. Там надо обязательно указывать режим (in / out) `std::ios::in bitor std::ios::binary bitor std::ios::ate` - открыть в бинарном режиме для чтения и поставить курсор в конец.

Answer (score 3):

Открываете файл с флагом `ios::ate`, который установит позицию потока в конец файла. Далее уже с помощью функции tellg получаете размер файла

```
fstream file( "example.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
return file.tellg();
```

Если [функция tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) вернула -1, значит вызов функции завершился с ошибкой.